# Store Object with Dynamic property in Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I have a message processor where I would like to take a lump of json with a wrapper of known schema, but with a property that is a dynamic object like the following:

```
public class NotificationDetails
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string NotificationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateSent { get; set; }
    public string TemplateUrl { get; set; }
    public dynamic Model { get; set; }
}
```

as you can see, the last property is of dynamic. the notifications will all have different Model schemas, so I would like it to just be stored as a nested object.

That said, when I attempt to Create the object via

```
client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, collectionId), item)
```

I get the following error message:

> The best overloaded method match for 'MyClass.CreateNotification(NotificationDetails))' has some invalid arguments

I thought I could throw anything into these docs. what am I doing wrong? should I use something other than dynamic for this Model property?

**UPDATE** I figured out it was something about how I was calling the Wait() method on the task returned from the DocumentClient. Once I reverted to the async await strategy it started working correctly.

Comment: Did you use cosmos sql api? I can't find any sdk has the method:CreateItemAsync<T>(T t);

Comment: I am using the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB nuget package. I am wrapping the  DocumentClient.CreateDocumentAsync method. I copied the wrong line. I'll edit my question to be more accurate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description. I have tested your code and it worked as below. You can refer to what I did:

```
    public static void CreateCosmosDocument()
    {
        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://xxxxx/"), "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJxxxxM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==", new ConnectionPolicy { EnableEndpointDiscovery = false });

        TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity { x = 11, y = 11, name = "wakaka", dynam = "hello dynam" };
        var createdItem = client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("ToDoList", "Items"), new NotificationDetails { DateCreated=DateTime.Now, DateSent=DateTime.Now, TemplateUrl="www.baidu.com", Model= testEntity });                     
    }
```

Class of NotificationDetails:

```
public class NotificationDetails
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string NotificationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateSent { get; set; }
    public string TemplateUrl { get; set; }
    public dynamic Model { get; set; }
}
```

Class of TestEntity which act as a nested object:

```
class TestEntity
{

    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public double x { get; set; }

    public double y { get; set; }

    public double z { get; set; }

    public dynamic dynam { get; set; }
}
```

Screenshot of result:

[image]

If the error still occured,  you'd better share your more detailed code with us for further research.

Comment: its super wierd.... I encapsulated the DocumentDB stuff in its own project, and wrap the DocumentClient in a Singleton repository.... when I  copy the same NotificationDetails class into the unit tests project, it works.... however, from my webapi project referencing this solution, it does not.... I will test further